# Is it possible to change the browser that pgadmin4 uses?

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4, debian

I have Debian 10, pgadmin4, and KDE. When I open pgadmin4, it opens with Firefox. I have several other browsers installed. If I try to paste the link in any other browser, I get this error message:

```
Unauthorized

The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.
```

Is there any way I can open it in another browser like Waterfox or Palemoon? My default browser is Waterfox. I can't find a pgadmin4.conf file to edit or a way to change it in the settings.

Comment: Does [this answer work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51637530/pgadmin-4-v3-1-how-can-i-use-another-browser-win-7) for you?

Comment: Direct URL doesn't work, you need copy URL with the session key then only it works in the different browsers.

Comment: @LowlyDBA I eventually found the icon that post refers to, and I was able to change it there in the configuration dialog box. Thank you!